# Does initialize in tornado.web.RequestHandler get called every time for a request/

Tags: python, tornado

There'a an `initialize` method in `tornado.web.RequestHandler` class, is it called every time there's a request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, tornado calls `initialize` for each request.

If you want to share state between requests(like db connection) - store it in `self.application`.

Comment: i can not find the `self.application` attribute/method anywhere.