# Initialize object once in Tornado web server

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization, tornado

I am building a web server using Tornado 4.5.1 and Python 3.6.
I want to initialize an object when starting the server and keep it available for the duration of the server run.

From this question: 
[Does initialize in tornado.web.RequestHandler get called every time for a request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199028/does-initialize-in-tornado-web-requesthandler-get-called-every-time-for-a-reques)
I understood that the initialize() functions inside RequestHandlers are called every time there is an HTTP request, and that to initialize once, I need to store this object inside the tornado.web.Application.

My question is: How I add this object to Application initialization? Do I need to subclass tornado.web.Application? Or is there API enabling this?
I couldn't understand this from the [Tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).

Comment: This is the single worst thing about `tornado` web server. No end to grief on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass the `Application` class and after that in your request handler you can access your application instance like [this](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#other):

```
RequestHandler.application
```

or if you are in method from your request handler

```
self.application
```

Let's suppose that you have added a variable `my_var` on your application, to access it you will do:

```
self.application.my_var
```

or

```
RequestHandler.application.my_var
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make it a module global:

```
my_global_var = set()  # Or whatever type of object you need
```

Then the variable will be initialized when your program starts, and last for the program's lifetime. This is the simplest and clearest way to do one-time initialization in Python.